# What effect does camera.up have in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm confused what effect changing the `camera.up` vector has in three.js.

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvanderdoes/zscjccLs/), I have `camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);`, but it doesn't look any different then the default y up vector. What *does* camera.up do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use functions like `Camera.lookAt()`, it will use the up vector to correctly orient the camera.

Comment: Would you mind forking the just fiddle above to demonstrate your answer?

Comment: Just after you set camera.up, do this: `camera.lookAt(0,0,0);`. Now, if you test different camera.up values, you'll see that the up vector is respected.

Comment: Wops, my bad - late night commenting. @WestLangley is right, `lookAt()` takes a `Vector3` argument.

Answer (score 0):

(extending kintel's answer) If you use functions like `camera.lookAt()`, it will use the up vector to correctly orient the camera. so if `camera.up.set(0,1,0)`, it would mean that y-axis is going vertically up in the screen and x and z axes align accordingly.

I have also uploaded an example in this site [here.](https://nilinswap.github.io/threesix/examples/car/index.html) Initially camera.up.set(0,1,0) is true, now play with buttons to see `camera.up.set` in action. find the code [here.](https://github.com/nilinswap/threesix/blob/master/examples/car/index.html)